# Logstash output different fields to different elastic search indices

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat

I have a `Filebeat` instance that sends `Apache` access logs to `Logstash`.
`Logstash` pipeline transforms the file and loads the processed fields say (**field1, field2 & field3**) to `elastic search`to an index **indexA**. The flow is simple & working. Here's my pipeline.conf

```
input{
    beats{
        port => "5043"
    }
}
filter 
{

    grok 
    {
        patterns_dir => ["/usr/share/logstash/patterns"]
        match =>{   "message" => ["%{IPORHOST:[client_ip]} - %{DATA:[user_name]} \[%{HTTPDATE:[access_time]}\] \"%{WORD:[method]} %{DATA:[url]} HTTP/%{NUMBER:[http_version]}\" %{NUMBER:[response_code]} %{NUMBER:[bytes]}( \"%{DATA:[referrer]}\")?( \"%{DATA:[user_agent]}\")?",
                    "%{IPORHOST:[remote_ip]} - %{DATA:[user_name]} \\[%{HTTPDATE:[time]}\\] \"-\" %{NUMBER:[response_code]} -" ] 
                }
        remove_field => "@version"
        remove_field => "beat"
        remove_field => "input_type"
        remove_field => "source"
        remove_field => "type"
        remove_field => "tags"
        remove_field => "http_version"
        remove_field => "@timestamp"
        remove_field => "message"
    }
    mutate
    {
        add_field => { "field1" => "%{access_time}" }
        add_field => { "field2" => "%{host}" }
        add_field => { "field3" => "%{read_timestamp}" }
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch{
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        index => "indexA"
    }
}
```

Now what I want to do is add three other fields **field4** and **field5** and add them to a seperate index named **indexB**. So at the end **indexA** holds **field1 field2** and **field3** while **IndexB** holds **field4** and **field5**

So far this is the modified pipeline.conf which doesn't seem to work.

```
input{
    beats{
        port => "5043"
    }
}
filter 
{

    grok 
    {
        patterns_dir => ["/usr/share/logstash/patterns"]
        match =>{   "message" => ["%{IPORHOST:[client_ip]} - %{DATA:[user_name]} \[%{HTTPDATE:[access_time]}\] \"%{WORD:[method]} %{DATA:[url]} HTTP/%{NUMBER:[http_version]}\" %{NUMBER:[response_code]} %{NUMBER:[bytes]}( \"%{DATA:[referrer]}\")?( \"%{DATA:[user_agent]}\")?",
                    "%{IPORHOST:[remote_ip]} - %{DATA:[user_name]} \\[%{HTTPDATE:[time]}\\] \"-\" %{NUMBER:[response_code]} -" ] 
                }
        remove_field => "@version"
        remove_field => "beat"
        remove_field => "input_type"
        remove_field => "type"
        remove_field => "http_version"
        remove_field => "@timestamp"
        remove_field => "message"
    }
    mutate
    {
        add_field => { "field1" => "%{access_time}" }
        add_field => { "field2" => "%{host}" }
        add_field => { "field3" => "%{read_timestamp}" }
    }   
}
output {
    elasticsearch{
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        index => "indexA"
    }
}
filter
{
    mutate
    {
        add_field => { "field4" => "%{source}" }
        add_field => { "field5" => "%{tags}" }
        remove_field => "field1"
        remove_field => "field2"
        remove_field => "field3"
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch{
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        index => "indexB"
    }
}
```

**Can someone please point out where I am going wrong or any alternative to the solution.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to duplicate your events using the [`clone` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-clone.html). Then you can add the desired fields to each respective event and sink them in two different ES indices:

```
input{
    beats{
        port => "5043"
    }
}
filter 
{

    grok 
    {
        patterns_dir => ["/usr/share/logstash/patterns"]
        match =>{   "message" => ["%{IPORHOST:[client_ip]} - %{DATA:[user_name]} \[%{HTTPDATE:[access_time]}\] \"%{WORD:[method]} %{DATA:[url]} HTTP/%{NUMBER:[http_version]}\" %{NUMBER:[response_code]} %{NUMBER:[bytes]}( \"%{DATA:[referrer]}\")?( \"%{DATA:[user_agent]}\")?",
                    "%{IPORHOST:[remote_ip]} - %{DATA:[user_name]} \\[%{HTTPDATE:[time]}\\] \"-\" %{NUMBER:[response_code]} -" ] 
                }
        remove_field => "@version"
        remove_field => "beat"
        remove_field => "input_type"
        remove_field => "type"
        remove_field => "http_version"
        remove_field => "@timestamp"
        remove_field => "message"
    }
    clone {
        clones => ["log1", "log2"]
    }
    if [type] == "log1" {
        mutate
        {
            add_field => { "field1" => "%{access_time}" }
            add_field => { "field2" => "%{host}" }
            add_field => { "field3" => "%{read_timestamp}" }
        }
    } else {   
        mutate
        {
            add_field => { "field4" => "%{source}" }
            add_field => { "field5" => "%{tags}" }
        }
    }
}
output {
    if [type] == "log1" {
        elasticsearch{
            hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
            index => "indexA"
        }
    } else {   
        elasticsearch{
            hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
            index => "indexB"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is helps my case perfectly.Extra thanks for modifying the code.